# Using static HttpClient vs a different HTTPClient for each set of Endpoint

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android

So my app involves a lot of network calls (probably connecting to 10 different servers) and fetching data. From couple of articles that I have read, reusing a HTTPClient instance is suggested as it prevents wastage of resources (sockets and such). But I am finding it tad difficult to design a module around a static HTTPClient which is extensible and robust. All my server connections needs different sets of headers, query parameters and such.
Would I be better off using a one HTTPClient per server/endpoint model.

Comment: That's why you set headers, content and parameters on a `HttpRequestMessage` and then `SendAsync()` instead of setting those things directly on the client instance.

Comment: And for things like access tokens, you could create a custom HttpMessageHandler

Comment: Cache the headers for the different domains and apply that to a request message when sending.

Comment: @nkosi Would you explain a bit on the caching header part. Do you mean a separate headers for each domain.

Comment: You stated that all your server connections needed different sets of headers, etc. If that information is stored in a delegate that can be applied to the request messages when being sent based on connection then you can keep the one client and just apply the necessary headers

Answer (score 2):

It's easier if you create a HttpClient instance for each server.

You can create a singleton class, as a wrapper for static httpClient and pass them with your Dependency Injection mechanism:

```
public class ServerAClient {
  private HttpClient _client;
  private static object _locker = new object();

  public static HttpClient GetInstance() {
    if (_client == null) {
      lock (_locker) {
        // create your httpclient here
        _client = instance;
      }
    }

    return _client;
  }
}

public class MyController : Controller {
  private readonly ServerAClient _aclient;
  public MyController(ServerAClient Aclient) {
    _aclient = Aclient;
  }

  public IHttpAction Index() {
    ...
   _aclient.DoSomething();
  }
}
```